# Why can't I authenticate a user when accessing my site from different URL...?

Tags: authentication

I'm having a problem authenticating users when I attempt to access my site using its URL.

```
Server: "SERVERNAME".
Access and authenticate fine at: "http://SERVERNAME".
DNS record: "intranet.domain.com"
Alternate Access Map: 
    Zone: "INTRANET"
    URL: "http://intranet.domain.com"
```

The problem is the same user does not authenticate when I access the site at "http://intranet.domain.com".

Just wondering what I should check...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem in the past and resolved by a registry change. See link below if that helps you

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861